# Html page is 100vh 100vw but bootstrap modal is taking space from the body which cause scroll bar in the page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

Here is the code summary below, so please help me how can get over from this problem:

```
<head>
</head>

<body>

<div id="myModal" class="modal">
</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't give the width/height 100vw/100vh.
In bootstrap , Modal has its pre-defined classes written. And the divs and other components have their own margins.
So better to keep the width 100% instead of 100vw.